# ¿Sabéis alguna forma de hacer animaciones en next.js que sea con javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animate.css, next.js

Intente hacer animaciones en next.js con Transition GroupReact Transition Group que esta en la documentación oficial de react pero este no hace ninguna.

Hice este ejemplo de la pagina oficial de react y no funciona en next.js.

importe la liberia

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Container, Button, Alert } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
```

Este código lo puse dentro del return y no hace la animación que debería hacer

```
 <Container style={{ paddingTop: '2rem' }}>
  {showButton && (
    <Button
      onClick={() => setShowMessage(true)}
      size="lg"
    >
      Show Message
    </Button>
  )}
  <CSSTransition
    in={showMessage}
    timeout={300}
    classNames="alert"
    unmountOnExit
    onEnter={() => setShowButton(false)}
    onExited={() => setShowButton(true)}
  >
    <Alert
      variant="primary"
      dismissible
      onClose={() => setShowMessage(false)}
    >
      <Alert.Heading>
        Animated alert message
      </Alert.Heading>
      <p>
        This alert message is being transitioned in and
        out of the DOM.
      </p>
      <Button onClick={() => setShowMessage(false)}>
        Close
      </Button>
    </Alert>
  </CSSTransition>
</Container>
```

Este código lo puse dentro del return y no hace la animación que debería hacer.

Comment: _ @Cokete Bienvenido a S.O. Español, Por favor compartenos el código de lo que has intentado, [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ¿has revisado si te muestra algún error en la consola de tu explorador?